# Return search promise

Tags: javascript, ember.js, promise

I am building a cordova app with Ember. An issue that I have run into is that Ember does not return a promise when the user changes input, but hangs when the search is processed.

```
App.SearchController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  name: "",
  products: null,
  loading : false,
  searchProducts: function(){
    this.set("loading", true);
    controller = this;
    var promise = new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        var productArray = App.Products.byString(controller.get("name").toLowerCase());
        resolve(productArray);
    }).then(function(arr){
        controller.set("products", arr);
        controller.set("loading", false);
    });
  }.observes("name")
});
```

In my `search` template, this is the search box :

```
{{input type="search" placeholder="Search products" class="form-control" value=name autofocus="autofocus"}}
```

But every time the user changes the input, the router blocks till the name is searched for and the results are displayed immediately, without the spinner spinning (if loading == true).

I think that I have implemented the Promise incorrectly. In that case, please do tell me where I am wrong.

**UPDATE 1**

```
"byString" : function(strSearch){
    products = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("data"));
    var productArray = [];
    var idlist = products.product_ids;
    var len = idlist.length;
    for(var i = 0; i < len; i++){
        var str = idlist[i].name.toLowerCase();
        if(str.match(strSearch)!=null && strSearch!=""){
            productArray.push(idlist[i]);
        }
    }
    return productArray;
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

The lag that I am experiencing is due to javascript processing the array. Can this not be handled by a Promise? Is there a way to prevent the router from blocking and wait for javascript to return its result, displaying the loader in the meanwhile?

Comment: what's `App.Products.byString(...)`, that isn't anything of Embers, so if you could include that above that'd be great.

Comment: @kingpin2k I forgot! Updated question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I see a point in implementing a promise here, it doesn't look like you're making any sort of asynchronous call.

That being said you are probably just experiencing rendering lag, or javascript lag, which will cause animated images etc to slow to a crawl.

You can prove this by adding a timeout before resolving.

```
  var promise = new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject){
       Em.run.later(function(){
          var productArray = App.Products.byString(controller.get("name").toLowerCase());
          resolve(productArray);
       }, 5000);
    }).then(function(arr){
        controller.set("products", arr);
        controller.set("loading", false);
    });
  }.observes("name")
```

Comment: Yes, it is a javascript processing lag. Isn't there any way to prevent the router from hanging when javascript is processing? I would have liked to display a loader when javascript was searching.

Comment: javascript is a single threaded language by standard, either your router is going, or your javascript is searching (it's a difficult thing to deal with in such a multiple thread world)...

Comment: So the JS delay, though only half-a-sec can't be handled. In that case I accept your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the PromiseProxyMixin http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.PromiseProxyMixin.html

Comment: Probably not useful in my case as the wait here is due to JavaScript processing and not async calls. Still thanks for the help.